# save header in a variable using php

Tags: php, header

I need help saving one header in a variable using php. My problem its that i have a header called **x-wap-msisdn**, and this header content  a information that i need.
My question its how can i get that header using php?
thanks for your help.

pd.

I use this code to be sure that i have that header:

```
<?php

$headers = apache_request_headers();
$xwap = "x-wap-msisdn";
foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
    echo "$header: $value <br />\n";

}
?>
```

thanks!.

Comment: `var_dump($headers['x-wap-msisdn'])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will set the desired header content into $header_content

```
<?php
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    $xwap = "x-wap-msisdn";
    $header_content = $headers[$xwap];

    //Output header content
    echo $header_content;
?>
```